# Why AVL sort is not in place?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, avl-tree, in-place

I was recently told that AVL sort is not in place. Can anyone please explain it? From the below code, I am not sure where I assign extra space when sorting. In this code, when a data structure is built or an element are inserted, elements are ordered by their key.

Reference for the claim: They are using this claim to motivate "binary heap"

[1].https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/lecture-notes/MIT6_006S20_r08.pdf

Reference for code:

[2]. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/lecture-notes/MIT6_006S20_r06.pdf

[3]. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/lecture-notes/MIT6_006S20_r07.pdf

```py
def height(A):
    if A: return A.height
    else: return -1

class Binary_Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.item = x
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.subtree_update()

    def subtree_update(self):
        self.height = 1 + max(height(self.left), height(self.right))

    def subtree_iter(self):
        if self.left: yield from self.left.subtree_iter()
        yield self
        if self.right: yield from self.right.subtree_iter()
        
    def subtree_first(self):
        if self.left: return self.left.subtree_first()
        else: return self
    
    def subtree_last(self):
        if self.right: return self.right.subtree_last()
        else: return self
        
    def sucessor(self):
        if self.right: return self.right.subtree_first()
        while self.parent and (self is self.parent.right): #A is parent's left child and A's parent exists
            self = self.parent
        return self.parent
        
    def predecessor(self):
        if self.left: return self.left.subtree_last()
        while self.parent and (self is self.parent.left):
            self = self.parent
        return self.parent
    
    def subtree_insert_before(self, A):
        if self.left: 
            self = self.left.subtree_last()
            self.right, A.parent = A, self
        else: 
            self.left, A.parent = A, self
        self.maintain()
        
    def subtree_insert_after(self, A):
        if self.right: 
            self = self.right.subtree_first()
            self.left, A.parent = A, self
        else: 
            self.right, A.parent = A, self
        self.maintain()
        
    def delete(self):
        if not self.left and not self.right: # when self is leaf
            if self.parent: 
                A = self.parent
                if A.left is self: A.left = None
                else: A.right = None
                self.parent = None
            
        if self.left: 
            self.item, self.left.subtree_last().item = self.left.subtree_last().item, self.item
            self.left.subtree_last().delete()
        
        else:
            self.item, self.right.subtree_first().item = self.right.subtree_first().item, self.item
            self.right.subtree_last().delete()
            
    def subtree_delete(self):
        if self.left or self.right:
            if self.left: B = self.predecessor()
            else: B = self.sucessor()
            self.item, B.item = B.item, self.item
            return B.subtree_delete()
            
        if self.parent:
            if self.parent.left is self: self.parent.left = None
            else: self.parent.right = None
            self.parent.maintain()
        return self
    
    def subtree_rotate_right(self):
        assert self.left
        B, E = self.left, self.right
        A, C = B.left, B.right
        B, self = self, B
        self.item, B.item = B.item, self.item
        B.left, B.right = A, self
        self.left, self.right = C, E
        if A: A.parent = B
        if E: E.parent = self
        B.subtree_update()
        self.subtree_update()
    
    def subtree_rotate_left(self):
        assert self.right
        A, D = self.left, self.right
        C, E = D.left, D.right
        self, D = D, self
        self.item, D.item = D.item, self.item
        self.left, self.right = A, C
        D.left, D.right = self, E
        if A: A.parent = self
        if E: E.parent = D
        self.subtree_update()
        D.subtree_update()
    
    def skew(self):
        return height(self.right) - height(self.left)
    
    def rebalance(self):
        if self.skew() == 2:
            if self.right.skew() < 0:
                self.right.subtree_rotate_right()
            self.subtree_rotate_left()
        elif self.skew() == -2:
            if self.left.skew() > 0:
                self.left.subtree_rotate_left()
            self.subtree_rotate_right()
    
    def maintain(self):
        self.rebalance()
        self.subtree_update()
        if self.parent: self.parent.maintain()
    
class Binary_Tree:
    def __init__(self, Node_Type = Binary_Node):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
        self.Node_Type = Node_Type
        
    def __len__(self): return self.size
    def __iter__(self):
        if self.root:
            for A in self.root.subtree_iter():
                yield A.item 
        
    def build(self, X):
        A = [x for x in X]
        def build_subtree(A, i, j):
            c = (i + j) // 2
            root = self.Node_Type(A[c])
            if i < c:
                root.left = build_subtree(A, i, c - 1)
                root.left.parent = root
            if j > c:
                root.right = build_subtree(A, c + 1, j)
                root.right.parent = root
            return root
        self.root = build_subtree(A, 0, len(A) - 1)
        
        
class BST_Node(Binary_Node):
    def subtree_find(self, k):
        if self.item.key > k:
            if self.left: self.left.subtree_find(k)
        elif self.item.key < k:
            if self.right: self.right.subtree_find(k)
        else: return self
        
        return None
    
    
    def subtree_find_next(self, k):
        if self.item.key <= k:
            if self.right: return self.right.subtree_find_next(k)
            else: return None
            
        elif self.item.key > k:
            if self.left: return self.left.subtree_find_next(k)
            else: return self 
        
        return self
        
    
    def subtree_find_prev(self, k):
        if self.item.key >= k:
            if self.left: return self.left.subtree_find_prev(k)
            else: return None
        elif self.item.key < k:
            if self.right: return self.right.subtree_find_prev(k)
            else: return self
        
        return self
    
    def subtree_insert(self, B):
        if B.item.key < self.item.key:
            if self.left: self.left.subtree_insert(B)
            else: self.subtree_insert_before(B)
        
        elif B.item.key > self.item.key:
            if self.right: self.right.subtree_insert(B)
            else: self.subtree_insert_after(B)
        
        else:
            self.item = B.item
        
        
class Set_Binary_Tree(Binary_Tree):
    def __init__(self): super().__init__(BST_Node)

    def iter_order(self): yield from self
    
    def build(self, X):
        for x in X: self.insert(x)
    
    def find_min(self): 
        if self.root: return self.root.subtree_first()
        
    def find_max(self): 
        if self.root: return self.root.subtree_last()
        
    def find(self, k):
        if self.root: 
            node = self.root.subtree_find(k)
            if node:
                return node.item
        
    def find_next(self, k): 
        if self.root:
            node = self.root.subtree_find_next(k)
            if node:
                return node.item
            
            
    def find_prev(self, k): 
        if self.root:
            node = self.root.subtree_find_prev(k)
            if node:
                return node.item
        
    def insert(self, x): 
        new = self.Node_Type(x)
        if self.root:
            self.root.subtree_insert(new)
            if new.parent is None: return False
            
        else:
            self.root = new
        
        self.size += 1
        return True
        
        
    def delete(self, k):
        assert self.root
        node = self.root.subtree_find(k)
        assert node
        ext = node.subtree_delete()
        if ext.parent is None: self.root = None
        self.size -= 1
        return ext.item
```

Comment: Please quote your source.

Comment: Please add references for both claims. Who says it runs in constant space and who says otherwise.

Comment: Please sketch how *AVL sort* works, and how it uses storage space (hyperlinks welcome *for reference&details*). I seem to remember AVL *trees*.

Comment: If you believe google, an AVL sort starts with an unsorted array. Then you build an AVL tree from the elements of the array. Finally, perform an inorder traversal of the AVL tree, putting the elements back into the array. It's quite possibly the worst O(NlogN) sort ever conceived in terms of execution time. Development time is also onerous, unless you already have the AVL code.

Comment: @user3386109 There you have it. You build an AVL tree. That's not in-place. "In-place" means "inside the array". But the AVL tree is not "inside the array".

Comment: Yes @Stef. That was my point. Perhaps you've confused me with the OP?

Comment: @OP The `__init__` method of a class is invoked when you instantiate (allocate memory for and initialize) an object of that class.
The line `root = self.Node_Type(A[c])` is allocating memory as part of the "build an AVL tree from the elements of the array" step.

Comment: @user3386109 Indeed I have confused you with the OP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) defines an in-place algorithm as follows:

> In computer science, an in-place algorithm is an algorithm which transforms input using no auxiliary data structure. However, a small amount of extra storage space is allowed for auxiliary variables. The input is usually overwritten by the output as the algorithm executes. An in-place algorithm updates its input sequence only through replacement or swapping of elements.

So one of the properties of an algorithm that is called "in-place" is that it does not copy all input values into an newly allocated data structure. If an algorithm creates a binary search tree (like AVL), for which node objects are created that are populated with the input values, then it cannot be called in-place by the above definition, even if at the end of the process the values are copied back into the input array.

As a comparison, heap sort does *not* have to create a new data structure, as the input array can be used to reorganise its values into a heap. It merely has to swap values in that array in order to sort it. It is therefore an in-place algorithm.